# My code is not leaving main

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to understand why my application is not leaving main ( launching).
I think this line is the cause.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil , nil);
```

The source code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     printf("I'm in main");

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    printf("\nafter the autiorealeas pool");

    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil , nil);

    printf("\nbefore the [pool relase] call");

    [pool release];
    printf("Leaving main");
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Don't fret! That's how it's supposed to be… :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right - it won't return!
[according to the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain)

> Return Value
>
> Even though an integer return type is specified, this function never returns. When users exits an iPhone application by pressing the Home button, the application moves to the background.

Comment: Except for the printf() calls this is the default template. I shouldn't even have to touch main at all for my app to launch.

Comment: That's right, you don't. The call to the function `UIApplicationMain()` begins the main UIKit runloop, from which your app will not exit until it terminates. You don't need to touch the `main()` function for normal UIKit apps.